# Cant find page in Xamarin.forms

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

i have some trouble finding the page that i wanna navigate to in Xamarin.forms. I've been looking everywhere and it seems i'm the only one experiencing the issue.

I have these 3 files:

[image]

And yet i keep getting an error on the new HomePage (could not be found). The class is right there, it just cant find it..

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
  {
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    void LoginButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       bool isIdEmpty = String.IsNullOrEmpty(idEntry.Text);
       bool isPasswordEmpty = String.IsNullOrEmpty(passwordEntry.Text);


        if(isIdEmpty || isPasswordEmpty)
        {

        } else
        {
            Navigation.PushAsync(new HomePage());
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it in another namespace?

Comment: We need to see how HomePage looks like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to see if both pages are in the same namespace. For instance, if `MainPage` is in the `YourApp` namespace:

```
namespace YourApp
{
    public class MainPage
    {
        // ... Your code
    }
}
```

and the `HomePage` is in the `YourApp.Pages` namespace, then you need to add a using statement to the top of your `MainPage`:

```
using YourApp.Pages;
// Probably other ones here

namespace YourApp
{
    public class MainPage
    {
        // ... Your code
    }
}
```

Or, you can specify the full namespace in your declaration: `Navigation.PushAsync(new YourApp.Pages.HomePage());`

Comment: You're a genius! Thanks alot! Now the xaml.cs page wont recognize the InitializeComponent method though .. Im tired

Comment: If you have changed your namespace, but sure that it is also changed in the XAML part of your page

Comment: Ah yeah, it was just a build / save issue, fixed itself. Thanks alot kind stranger!

Comment: No problem at all, don't forget to accept it as an answer!